# Shadow map appearing on wrong place

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm trying to make use of the built-in shadow map plugin in three.js. After initial difficulties I have more or less acceptable image with one last glitch. That one being shadow appearing on top some (all?) surfaces, with normal 0,0,1. Below are pictures of the same model.

Three.js
[image: Three.js]

Preview.app (Mac)

[image: Preview.app]

And the code used to setup shadows:

```
    var shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF);
    shadowLight.position.x = cx + dmax/2;
    shadowLight.position.y = cy - dmax/2;
    shadowLight.position.z = dmax*1.5;
    shadowLight.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(cx, cy, 0));
    shadowLight.target.position.set(cx, cy, 0);
    shadowLight.castShadow = true;
    shadowLight.onlyShadow = true;
    shadowLight.shadowCameraNear    =  dmax;
    shadowLight.shadowCameraFar     =  dmax*2;
    shadowLight.shadowCameraLeft    = -dmax/2;
    shadowLight.shadowCameraRight   =  dmax/2;
    shadowLight.shadowCameraBottom  = -dmax/2;
    shadowLight.shadowCameraTop     =  dmax/2;
    shadowLight.shadowBias          =  0.005;
    shadowLight.shadowDarkness      =  0.3;
    shadowLight.shadowMapWidth      =  2048;
    shadowLight.shadowMapHeight     =  2048;
    // shadowLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    scene.add(shadowLight);
```

UPDATE: And a live example over here: http://jsbin.com/okobum/1/edit

Comment: Can you provide a live (and simple) example?

Comment: I just made a small demo, lowered the shadow resolution though, since the scene contains a single model and a cube for comparison. Now how do I make this look pretty? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. You just need to play with the `shadowLight.shadowBias` parameter. This is always a bit tricky. (Note that the bias parameter can be negative.)

EDIT: Tighten up your shadow-camera near and far planes. This will help reduce both shadow acne and peter-panning. For example, your live link, set `shadowLight.shadowCameraNear = 3*dmax;`. This worked for me.

You can also try adding depth to your table tops, if it's not already there.

You can try setting `renderer.shadowMapCullFrontFaces = false`. This will cull back faces instead of front ones.

Comment: It's no go, the acne goes away with lower absolute values, but then starts appearing on larger objects. I think the whole technique is not suited for scene where geometry size varies wildly, like when you have couple of very details objects and some very big and simple. What do you think?

Comment: I think that shadow mapping artifacts have to be handled on a case-by-case basis. I'm not too sure about your hypothesis. Nice demo, by the way.

Comment: Can you consider this question "answered"?

Comment: Not really. That artifact is gone with higher bias, but peter panning occurs instead. I'm still looking into this, I suspect buggy depthRGBA shader in THREE.js. I'm not sure what you mean by case-by-case basis. I tried setting up multiple lights, tight fighting shadow camera frustum, it's no help.

Comment: I said case-by-case basis because problems tend to be geometry-specific. Hence, I can only give you things to try -- I can't give you a "solution". See EDIT in answer.