# Three.js - bug with shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shadow

I'm doing some tests with three.js but I have a problem with shadows.
You can see a screenshot of the bug here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv91w9fkhfnhzkv/bug%20shadow%20fleche.jpg

More precisely, the two things red and blue are CubeGeometry, and the ground is a PlaneGeometry. I have tried to put the ground at the middle height of the CubeGeometry but this is don't solve the problem.

I have try a lot of different settings but the bug remains. Here are my currently render settings :

```
directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
directionalLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true }  );
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912126/shadow-map-appearing-on-wrong-place

Comment: It is not exactly the same problem. I have try other things but the bug remains :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by setting shadowBias property.

```
    directionalLight.shadowBias = 0.0015;
```